# Should you immediately attain max glide speed after engine failure?

Tags: emergency, engine-failure, cessna-172, emergency-procedures

For the Cessna 172 Skyhawk maximum glide is attained at a speed of 65 KIAS. If you're flying well above this speed, let's say 90 KIAS, and suffer an engine failure, what would be the best practice: immediately slow down in order to achieve 65 KIAS as soon as possible, or slow down slowly?

Comment: Is waiting to slow down in a C172 without any thrust too long for you?

Comment: There may be some C172 models that list best glide speed as 60 KIAS, but that is not a speed that I am familiar with. The last two models that I flew—C172M and C172R, listed 80 mph (70 KIAS) and 65 KIAS, respectively. In the interest of accuracy and safety, if 60 KIAS is in fact a valid speed, you should specify the model.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Did you have something else to do?

Comment: When you pull up to drop your speed, you are trading speed for altitude, something you'll appreciate as time goes on.

Comment: It isn't necessarily a bad question, because aggressive acceleration might rob energy that might otherwise go to extending the glide.

Comment: @JonathanWalters you are correct, searching online POHs seems to show 65 KIAS is the most common best glide speed for the C172. I've edited my question to reflect this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: If you were able to transfer all the excess kinetic energy into altitude, you could theoretically gain 2200ft. However, if you pull up aggressively to quickly increase your altitude, you will lose a lot of energy due to the increased drag. Gently pulling up and climbing while the airspeed is bleeding of is the most efficient way to preserve the energy. When approaching 65 knots, stop your climb (this can be a relatively quick pitch down) and maintain the max glide speed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the amplified emergency procedures of the Cessna 172 Model N POH (emphasis added):

> After an engine failure in flight, the best glide speed shown in Figure 3-1 should be established **as quickly as possible.**

The same POH lists 65 KIAS as the best-glide speed.

Time spent away from best glide means less glide range. If increasing time, not glide range, is your goal then the minimum sink rate speed would be what you would want to fly. In an emergency, time and glide range give you more options.

The POH and physics agree: yes, establish best-glide speed immediately after an engine failure.

Comment: You can also use that excess air speed to increase your altitude slightly before setting up for best-glide attitude. It could all help in an emergency.

Comment: @Ads I think this is key. The question is, should Iget to that speed as quickly as possible? If it means killing speed using e.g. drag, that lost energy is probably **worse** than getting to glide speed *slowly*. If however the emergency still allows enough control to use altitude to slow down, than *that* energy is stored as potential and is reusable. In this case, it is **better** to do it as quickly as possible. Anyone agree?

Comment: How about - hold your altitude until at best glide speed?

Comment: The key point is to immediately establish the optimum angle of attack for glide and hold it, which will most efficiently convert speed to altitude. The problem is that most GA do not have a precision AOA meter and pitch is a poor substitute.